# Apply custom markers to specific value of pytest parameterized marker

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1])
def test_increment(a):
    pass
```

I want to apply custom-marker to a specific value of a marker. In the above-mentioned test case to be should be executed with

- a=0 if `-m one` is provided.
- a=1 if `-m two` is provided.

I tried the following snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [pytest.mark.one(0), pytest.mark.two(1)])
def test_increment(a):
    pass
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context? It's unclear why you'd want this, or whether parametrized tests make sense for it.

Comment: sure, give me 2 minutes. I'll add more context

Comment: Actually, I am marking all my test cases in two categories. however, this one test case is parameterized whose param-values fall in both the categories. For that test case, I want to mark specific values so that only those parameter-value would be executed.

Comment: It would probably be less confusing to have one test for each category, and just duplicate those values that fall into both.

Comment: Let me give an exact example. I have 2 types of tests. A & B. A has dependency x. B has dependency y. I have created a test `test_splunk_dependecy()`. The test should only check for x dependency if `-m A` is provided. And it should check for y dependency if `-m B` is provided. Creating 2 test which does the exact same thing doesn't make much sense to me. the only variable is the dependency name. that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to provide custom marker to a parametrized test using `pytest.param`.

Document link: 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-param

Example: 
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#set-marks-or-test-id-for-individual-parametrized-test

Snippet

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [pytest.param(0, marks=pytest.mark.one), pytest.param(1, marks=pytest.mark.two)])
def test_increment(a):
    pass
```